# Is it possible to connect a camera to an arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun

I working on a project that requires a small camera to be covering a (insect) nest entrance. The video needs to be transmitted to a computer to be processed. I am interfacing with Java using the RXTX library and will then be tracking objects using OpenCV.

[This is the camera](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/321943226649)

My question is, it it possible to connect this camera to an Arduino (Uno or Yun) and transmit the data back to a computer?

Comment: Why don't you get a camera that connects directly to the PC?

Comment: @Gerben i don't think the insects will slow a PC near there nest.

Comment: I'd just go with a raspberry pi, and usb-webcam of the pi-camera-module. Then you could even run the OpenCV on the Pi itself. Having and Arduino, some camera, some kind of networking shield will quickly become expensive. PS what do you mean by the word `slow`?

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, the connection between the computer and the camera would be wireless. Would this be possible with the pi camera? The other option, is to scrap the Arduino and use a wireless transmitter and receiver set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out ArduCam. Do a google search. http://www.arducam.com

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused about the Arducam. Am I able to just use the library with the camera that I specified or do I need to purchase the Arducam camera? Also, would I need the shield?

Comment: I didn't mean shield, I meant the board that they are using for the camera, but I think that it is just an Uno

Comment: I picked up one of these Arducam Mini Module Camera Shield 5 Megapixels OV5642 Camera Module for Arduino UNO Mega2560 Board https://www.amazon.com/dp/B013JUKZ48/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_wlbKxbSN0G2KK You find cheaper ones on eBay b